# Laravel POST request working in Local and throwing 500 on the remote server(digital ocean)

Tags: laravel, deployment, laravel-5

I am creating API using Laravel 5! I tested the services(Get & POST) locally, but when deployed on the remote server(Droplet on Digital Ocean) the POST requests doesn't work.

Is there any configuration changes i need to make in the project to allow POST/PUT calls?

In my local machine,I am using a XAMPP and on the remote machine, i use a LAMP stack on a digital ocean droplet and AWS RDS for mysql. Is there any configuration changes i have to make on my remote apache instance to allow POST calls?

Also i disabled the CSRF validation in the laravel app i deployed.

Comment: Any errors are being thrown?

Comment: This could be a multitude of things. You will need to tell us what error message you're getting for us to be able to help you. If you're only seeing the "Whoops!" message then just make sure that you're `debug` in you're `.env` file is set to `true`.

Comment: I checked the storage/laravel.log and apache_errors.log, but i don't see anything there! The 'debug' is true in .env, but still can' see any error log!
I'm editing the question with more details about my local and remote stack!

Answer (score 1):

go to app->http->kernel

open kernel file:

```
protected $middleware = [
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
//  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, // this is the csrf token, just disable using '//'
 ];
```